# Returning File + text in ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am htting a Controller Action which returns a File(fileName, type) in the ActionResult. I want to tack on some text along with the image being returned, so that I can use it on the client. Is there a known good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encode the image data as Base64 and return a JSON object structured as follows:

```
{
    "Text": "Some text...",
    "Image": "<base64 encoded image data>"
}
```